# TFS: Overwrite (ALL) local file or folder

Tags: tfs, tfvc

I'm trying to get latest on Visual Studio 2017/Angular project on a another machine and hence getting latest all files. It is taking a long time to 'Overwrite local file or folder' individually. Isn't there a way to Overwrite All local files or folders with single click?

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, from the Source Control Explorer, open the folder you want to overwrite. Use <kbd>Advanced...</kbd>, <kbd>Get Specific Version...</kbd>

[image]

And check the option "Overwrite writable files..."

[image]

Optionally check "Overwrite all files", but that should not be required and can take up more time.

You can also do this from the commandline:

```
tf vc get $/project/path /recursive /overwrite /version:T
```

And optionally to overwrite all files even if your system thinks they are unchanged:

```
tf vc get $/project/path /recursive /overwrite /force /version:T
```

Alternatively, you can use undo pending changes to revert to the last checked-in version, or scorch to clear files that aren't even checked in:

```
tf vc undo /recursive $/Project/path
```

and

```
tf vc scorch /recursive $/project/path
```